# C# based framework for JQuery functions

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, frameworks

Is there any C# based framework application where easily developers can add jquery functions and get immediate effect accordingly in presentation layer ? if no then can anybody suggest any idea regarding the following req:

I am going to build the the mega drop down control in asp.net which should be build like customizable behavior. means if any developer in my team wants to change the look and feel as well as effects then he should able to copy only required jquery function from referenced library. Is this possible? I need the champs guidance in this scenario. Any suggestions would be appreciable... If my concern is wrong somewhere ...you guys can ask for clearance around the framework. I think this framework will helpful for all c# + jquery developers...isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Although jQuery is a client-side language and C# is used in server-side, But for ease of use, jQuery has been integrated with .NET to be used more easily from the server-side.

[DotNetAge](http://www.dotnetage.com/) is one of these frameworks. altrhough, I haven't had a good experience with it myself. You can find more info at http://www.dotnetage.com/sites/home/dj-jquery-web-contorls-for-asp-net.html.

Plus, if you're using ASP.NET MVC, you'd be better off to do the client-side code yourself (Acutally, it's easier too).

Comment: hey hi Kamyar...thanks for shearing your great idea dude. I think ASP.NET MVC is good only in the sense, when we are using our jquery based control as user control. where as my planning is to make developers available this framework as platform independent so that people can only need to install it, select the control they want to use and just copy the .js file, add its path to one of property of control and copy - paste the required function in the given input box. I don't know If you experienced with customizing CRM module...there is such type of facility available provided by Microsoft,

Comment: where we need only copy-past the the JavaScript function and change the parameters accordingly and shows immediate effect as such... i need this kind of architecture.

Comment: Well, I think you need to create web user controls. Also, You can embed JS in your user control using WebResources.axd. That's how MS puts required JS for its controls (e.g. validators). This way users don't need to include any .js file manually. Just server-side and drag-n-drop. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

All of the famous control creators such as

- Infragistics
- Telerik

Are offering jQuery based Controls just have a look here http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/jquery-controls.aspx or for ASP.NET MVC here http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx

Cheers

Comment: :) thanks buddy. but i wanted to build the framework for these type of control for invent new controls. these are already built. any suggestions regrading architecture

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

when you're going to build a control itself, you should consider to put everything you need into an ASP.NET WebControl. Including the JavaScript which is required.

So the developer only have to put the ASP.NET Control on his page and everything works fine. Sure, putting just a jQuery function into the page is fine too, but it isn't the way you normally do ASP.NET Development.

When you're building an ASP.NET WebControl as mentioned earlier you have to ensure that it's possible to put the same control more than once on a page. In many situations you have to thnik about that while designing your JS.

I hope that's what you're lookin for